# Why is Element-plus not working inside storybook?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, storybook, vite, element-plus

I have done everything in accordance with the docs.
I installed `storybook`, and then I changed the config file the way they say has to be done to make storybook work on `Vite`, which supports the `element-plus` library.

.storybook/main.js:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-vite', //  The builder enabled here.
  },
}
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "elementui-practice",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 4173",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "element-plus": "^2.2.17",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.38"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.1",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/builder-vite": "^0.2.2",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@storybook/vue3": "^6.5.12",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.4",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.5.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "vite": "^3.0.9",
    "vue-cli-plugin-storybook": "~2.1.0",
    "vue-loader": "^16.8.3"
  }
}
```

If I run only the `element-plus` (`npm run dev`), the library works.
If I run `npm run storybook`, `element-plus` styles are not applied to the components or elements. Normal css works, but `element-plus` components and styles do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these code to storybook's preview.js

```js
import { app } from '@storybook/vue3'; //I use Vue3
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus';
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css';

app.use(ElementPlus);
```

Comment: need restart or refresh.

Answer (score 2):

There's a slight change in Storybook 7 onwards, since it doesn't export
`app` anymore. Do this instead:

```js
import {setup} from '@storybook/vue3'
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css'

setup((app) => {
  app.use(ElementPlus)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line  in my `main.ts` solved my issue

```
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css';
```